# iOS 10/Xcode 8 TestFairy not logging

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8, testfairy

I tried googling and reading newest `TestFairy` documentation, but nothing worth of mention there. My problem is next: I upgraded `Xcode` to 8, and created new build that I uploaded on `TestFairy`. Everything is working normal, except **now I don't see application logs**. Anyone else experienced same issue?

***Note: Everything worked fine with Xcode 7 and iOS 10.***

Comment: Not using TestFairy, but similar experience here; logs diverted to a log file with asl_add_log_file() do not get written with Xcode 8/iOS 10. Xcode 8 to iOS 10 simulator, works, but not on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for TestFairy

Apple changed their log apis with [iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) effectively barring libraries from ours from collecting logs from a device. We've suggested a workaround which asks developers to either use TFLog instead of NSLog, or create a macro forwarding all calls to NSLog to TFLog. This is described in our docs which are available [here](https://docs.testfairy.com/iOS_SDK/Logs_on_iOS_10.html).